# How do I make multiple self joins in mysql?

Tags: mysql, join

I am working on a genealogy database. In simple terms a single table called `ancestors`, consists of records with the following structure:

```
 name_id | name | mother_id | father_id
---------+------+-----------+-----------
       1 | John |         2 |         3
       2 | Mary |         4 |         5
       3 | Dave |         6 |         7
```

The first query finds parent ids for John:
eg  John has parents with ids 2 and 3

Then two further queries find the parent names for the parent ids:
Parent id 2 has the name Mary, and Parent id 3 has the name Dave

Three queries have been used to find that:
John has parents called Mary and Dave.

Can this be done with a single query, and will there be any gain in performance?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT me.name,
       mother.name,
       father.name
  FROM ancestors me
  JOIN ancestors mother
    ON me.mother_id = mother.name_id
  JOIN ancestors father
    ON me.father_id = father.name_id
 WHERE ancestors.id = 1
;
```

And yes, it's generally faster to run the above than to run three separate lookup queries.

Answer (score 2):

Join as you usually would, but simply use the same table each time, giving each join a unique alias:

```
SELECT people.name_id, people.name, mothers.name_id, mothers.name, ...
FROM people
LEFT JOIN people AS mothers ON people.mother_id = mothers.name_id
LEFT JOIN people AS fathers ON people.father_id = fathers.name_id
etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at  graph noSQL databases.
They are the perfect fit for what you plan to do:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FlockDB
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Graph